# How to request moving this bug report to the correct package/team?

Tags: bug-reporting

There is a bug in Ubuntu's keyboard shortcuts that is still very much active but was reported incorrectly in gnome-terminal and was eventually marked as "Fix Released" for reasons I do not comprehend. It is this one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292113

It is a pretty serious bug that causes various keys and key combinations to stop working for no discernible reason.

How can I request that this is moved to whichever bug team it should belong to (who that is, I'm not quite sure -- if anyone knows, tell me)? Do I have to file a new report, or do the official people have the ability to move it? Should I cite the old report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Fix Released* message is probably due to comments [#5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292113/comments/5) and [#10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292113/comments/10), where OP says:

> @Alfredo: Non-working FN-keys is not related to this issue.
>
> Also regarding the original bug report. This issue is fixed for me
>   since the release date.
>
> ---
>
> I do not have this issue anymore since a long time. Might be fixed with 14.10.

You should file a new bug.

You could cite the old report. However, since the person who filed that doesn't have this problem any more, and since the post was rather specifically about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>, it's not sure you have the same problem, or even that it's related. I don't see much use of linking to the old one from the new report. You could comment on the old report that you made a new bug report, so that others who subscribed are notified.